# adding a class is not listing collection with ClassList.add

Tags: javascript, css, if-statement

I am trying to write a time stamp that will be green when open and display closed in black font when closed.  The following code seems like it should work.  It is parsing the time correctly but it is not selecting the element.
Please take a look:

```html
<style>
  .closed-sign {
    display: inline;
    display: none;
  }
</style>
<script>
  var myDate = new Date();
  var time = 12;
  alert(time);
  //hour in military

  if ((time < 9) || (time >= 17)) {
    alert("we are closed");
    var openHours = document.getElementById("open");
    openHours.classList.add("closed-sign");
    var closedHours = document.getElementById('closed');
    closedHours.classList.remove("closed-sign");
  }

  if ((time > 9) && (time <= 17)) {
    alert("we are open");
    var openHours = document.getElementById("open");
    openHours.classList.remove("closed-sign";)

    var closedHours = document.getElementById("closed");

    closedHours.classList.add("closed-sign");

  }
</script>

<div style="float: right;" id="open" class="closed-sign">
  <p><span style="color: black">open: </span><span style="color: green;">9:00am - 5pm</span>
</div>
<div style="float: right;" id="closed" class="">
  <p><span style="color: black">closed </span>
</div>
```

Shouldn't this work. I have tried several things even looping through the collection but nothing is working.  I currently discarded trying to do it by class and went to trying to select element by id but I can't add or remove a class for some reason.  Could anyone see why? thank you.

Comment: `seems like it should work` Don't think so, check browser console for errors

Comment: I did there are no errors, you say you don't think so, that's what I said only I tried it. If you don't know just say so.  Thanks

Comment: Run the snippet you posted if you don't believe me. It has a syntax error. You need to fix that first.

Answer (score 1):

There is an Syntax error in your script -

```
closedHours.classList.remove("closed-sign";)
```

Change it to -

```
closedHours.classList.remove("closed-sign");
```

> Place your `JavaScript` code after `HTML` code Or Place your `JavaScript` code into `window.onload` **Event** like as-

```
window.onload = function(){
    /*Place your all JavaScript code here*/
}
```

**Note :** Here is the details about [window.onload Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

Comment: good try but that's hot it.  This is a difficult question I just thought I'd see if the experts knew.  It appears they don't i'll keep at it.  Thanks for trying

Answer (score 0):

Hi there was syntax error in code

```
openHours.classList.remove("closed-sign";)
```

code should be

```
openHours.classList.remove("closed-sign");
```

and load scripts in bellow the html, I changed the code putting scripts in bellow. this is 100% working check this.

```
<style>
    .closed-sign {
        display: inline;
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<div style="float: right;" id="open" class="closed-sign" >
    <p><span style="color: black">open: </span><span style="color: green;">9:00am - 5pm</span>
</div>
<div style="float: right;" id="closed" class="" >
    <p><span style="color: black">closed </span>
</div>
<script>
    var myDate = new Date();
    var time = 12;
    alert(time);
    //hour in military

    if ((time <9) || (time >= 17)){
        alert("we are closed");
        var openHours = document.getElementById("open");
        openHours.classList.add("closed-sign");
        var closedHours = document.getElementById('closed');
        closedHours.classList.remove("closed-sign");
    }

    if ((time > 9) && (time <= 17)){
        alert("we are open");
        var openHours = document.getElementById("open");
        openHours.classList.remove("closed-sign");
        var closedHours = document.getElementById("closed");
        closedHours.classList.add("closed-sign");
    }
</script>
```